# how can i convert pfx to crt/pem on shared hosting like Godaddy with PHP Script?

Tags: php, digital-signature, tcpdf, php-openssl

I need to create digitally signed PDF with PFX files. I am using TCPDF for this, but TCPDF works with PEM/CRT files.
If i upload file on the shared hosting and try to convert the file it is always zero KB.

This is the code i have tried.

```
exec('openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nocerts -out keyfile-encrypted.key');
```

Comment: What happens when you perform `openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nocerts -out keyfile-encrypted.key` from the command line? It will probably lead you to ["openssl pkcs12" site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q="openssl+pkcs12"+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: thank you ! but i figured it out.. extracted private key and certificate in separate new files with .key and .cer extensions respectively. @jww

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

- I believe for digital signing you need both the private key and the certificate, in PEM form.  You've used the `-nocerts` option, so you're only getting the private key.  Remove that option to keep the certificate as part of the PEM export.
- If the PFX file you have is encrypted, then you need to somehow feed the encryption password to the `openssl` command to decrypt the PFX file.  If you're getting a 0KB file from `openssl`, it is possible it's detecting the non-interactive nature of your request and exiting.
- You need to specify the -nodes option on the `openssl` command to prevent `openssl` from trying to encrypt the resulting file.  Again, if `openssl` is waiting for input (an encryption password) but detecting a non-interactive call, it may just be failing out without writing anything to the file.
- Use the output and return var parameters of the `exec` call in PHP to determine what's going wrong:

  exec('openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nocerts -out keyfile-encrypted.key', $output, $retval);

The `$output` variable should contain the output from the command; the `$retval` variable will contain the return code, which you can then check against openssl's documentation.

Comment: thank you ! but i figured it out..
extracted private key and certificate in separate new files with .key and .cer extensions respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer much more confusing than it needs to be. I wanted to use the pfx file to set up an Nginx reverse proxy. The use case is slightly different, but it boils down to the same: You need a .crt file and a .key file. This is done in two parts. I did this in a Linux terminal.

Get the Public Certificate file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in ./cert.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out public.crt
```

Get the Private Key file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in ./cert.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out private.key
```

You might be asked for an "Import Password", which you will have to get from the originator of the .pfx file.